# Parsing DoneDone API time

Tags: parsing, time

DoneDone's API returns dates as strings that look like "`/Date(1447595230347)/`". Trying to figure out how and why it's in this format and how I can parse it in JS. Any ideas?

https://www.getdonedone.com/api/